# Why do I get uninitialized constant Spree::Admin::CheckoutsController (NameError) for my decorator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, spree

I have an existing decorator which looks like this:

**app/controllers/products_controller_decorator.rb**

```
  1 module Spree
  2   Admin::ProductsController.class_eval do
  3     def update_stock_location
            # my custom code
```

^ That works.

But when I'm trying to create a new decorator for the CheckoutsController, I get this error:

```
app/controllers/checkouts_controller_decorator.rb:2:in 
`<module:Spree>': uninitialized constant Spree::Admin::CheckoutsController (NameError)
        from /Users/martins/Work/SolidusApp/app/controllers/checkouts_controller_decorator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /Users/martins/Work/SolidusApp/config/application.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Application>'
```

This is what my Spree::Admin::CheckoutsController looks like:
**app/controllers/checkouts_controller_decorator.rb**

```
  1 module Spree
  2   Admin::CheckoutsController.class_eval do
  3
  4     def complete
            # my custom code
```

I don't understand why it get an `uninitialized constant Spree::Admin::CheckoutsController (NameError)`. The files looks identical to me.

This is the original class:

**solidus/api/app/controllers/spree/api/checkouts_controller.rb**

```
  1 module Spree
  2   module Api
  3     class CheckoutsController < Spree::Api::BaseController
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `Api::CheckoutsController` not `Admin::CheckoutsController`

```
module Spree
  Api::CheckoutsController.class_eval do
    # ...
```

---

Others who find this answer may be looking for `Admin::CheckoutController` (singular, no 's' after checkout)

Comment: No, I'm sorry, that's not correct. I've updated the post with some excerpts from the original class.

Comment: @martins then you want `Api::CheckoutsController` not `Admin::CheckoutsController`

Comment: THAT'S IT! :-D Can't belive I didn't see that myself. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your answer to reflect the correct solution.